# Mimic STRING_SPLIT without custom function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

It is asked many times, but not this way.

I am on SQL Server 2008, and there is no `STRING_SPLIT` function (like in 2016).

A query returns with the following row, see below a single example row. What you see below in bald is a single field actually, so one `varchar` column has it altogether:

```
Appple|10|admin|845687|Apr|26|11:32:29|2016|AwesomeApplication.zip
```

which I'd like to be split by the pipe `|` character.

I cannot write a CTE for this, or a custom function.

I have to extract the individual pipe delimited elements, into different columns, within one select statement using the built in string functions like `CHARINDEX`, `PATINDEX`.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: If its a single string just copy the code from a while-loop split function and use it inline, there will be a point at which each token is exposed

Comment: @AlexK. edited the question to make it more clear ... it actually one field coming from a query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Result Table(Value varchar(50))
DECLARE @x XML
SELECT @X = CAST('<A>' + REPLACE(@StringList, '|', '</A><A>') + '</A>' AS XML)

INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT t.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as inVal
FROM @X.nodes('/A') AS x(t)
```

This will create a table with one column (Value).  Each split value from your pipe-delimited string will create a new record in this table.  Then you can join to it however you'd like.  Please let me know if this is unclear or if it doesn't work on SQL 2008.

You can increase the size of the varchar, if needed - and you can modify the query to split on different values (comma-delimited, etc.).

Comment: this gave me the idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[split] 
(
    @string varchar(max), 
    @separator varchar(1) -- longer separator is also possible
)
RETURNS 
@result TABLE (keyword varchar(max) )
AS
BEGIN
declare @pos int=0, @res varchar(100)
while len(@string)>0
begin
set @pos=CHARINDEX(@separator, @string+@separator,0)
select @res=left(@string,@pos),@string=SUBSTRING(@string,@pos+1,100)
insert @result values(@res)
end
    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while since this question was asked, and although the OP wanted a non-function solution, this is the only post where the answer pointed me in the right direction for me to write my code, so I thought I'd share my solution here.

#### What it does

This code, checks the `master` db compatibility mode and creates an appropriate `_my_string_split` function. If `string_split` exists, this is just a wrapper.
If not it will use the method [Stan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3200592/stan-shaw) proposed in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37078469/799379)

So now, regardless of where I'm running my code, after creating the function, all I need to do is use `master.dbo._my_string_split`, for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM master.dbo._my_string_split('Hello|World!','|')
```

#### The Code

```sql
USE master
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo._my_string_split') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[_my_string_split]
GO

DECLARE @sqlCode NVARCHAR(MAX);
IF 130 <= (SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME()) 
    SET @sqlCode = '
    --- 130+ string_split exists
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[_my_string_split]
    (
        @string nvarchar(max),
        @separator nvarchar(1)
    )
    RETURNS
    @result TABLE ([Value] nvarchar(max) )
    BEGIN   

        INSERT INTO @result
            SELECT [Value] FROM string_split(@string,@separator)

        RETURN

    END
'
ELSE
  SET @sqlCode = '
    --- before 130: string_split does not exists
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[_my_string_split]
    (
        @string nvarchar(max),
        @separator nvarchar(1)
    )
    RETURNS
    @result TABLE ([Value] nvarchar(max) )
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @result
            SELECT [Value]=t.value(''.'', ''varchar(max)'')
            FROM (SELECT x=(CAST((''<A>'' + REPLACE(@string, @separator, ''</A><A>'') + ''</A>'') AS XML))) a
            CROSS APPLY a.x.nodes(''/A'') AS x(t)

        RETURN

    END
'

PRINT @sqlCode
EXEC sp_sqlexec @sqlCode
```

Hope others will find this useful.